# c# : Delay in task for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

Hi can you help me add a delay in the forloop inside the Battle Task? Im unsure how to do it, and just recently started learning c#

```
var Battle = new Task(() => 
{
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 3; ctr++)
        Console.WriteLine(" In battle {0}", ctr);
});

Battle.Start();
Battle.Wait();
```

I want a delay between every counting like this:

In battle 1
(delay1000)
In battle 2
(delay1000)
In battle 3

Comment: `Task.Delay()`?

Comment: I've changes my description a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<Task> battleFactory = async() => 
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: In battle {1}", sw.Elapsed, i );
    }
};

Task battle = battleFactory();
battle.Wait();
```

see live sample at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9hOVhJ)